# Combustibility of gas/carbon dioxide mix

Tags: combustion, hydrogen, hydrocarbons

Via electrolysis I [produced](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48136/creating-ethane-through-electrolysis-of-vinegar) an ethane/hydrogen/carbon dioxide mix. Normally, there is 1 part ethane, 1 part hydrogen and 2 parts carbon dioxide. If I simply used a Bunsen burner with air hole closed to try to burn this gas, would it burn at all? Would the hydrogen burn properly but the ethane produce lots of soot and carbon monoxide?

Comment: I say this not entirely in jest, but..why not try it out and see for yourself?

Comment: Can't, because I don't have any pipes that won't melt right now, and am busy so can't really get any right now

Comment: Then try it when you can. Chemistry is an experimental science, after all. My guess is that it would burn quite readily.

Comment: @IvanNeretin  This makes me wonder.  Are many or most electrolytic gas mixtures self combustible?  Could the changes to the electrolyte result in some fuel or oxidiser component not being a gas leaving only one or the other type requiring external air or fuel for combustion?

Comment: Many (though not most) electrolytic gas mixtures contain hydrogen, hence yes, they are combustible. If by _"self combustible"_ you mean _"containing both oxidant and reducing agent"_, then the right word is _"explosive"_. Some mixtures are like that, some aren't.